# Django: 1 database shared by N applications

Tags: python, django

I want to share a models.py between several applications. The database tables should be created from models.py using manage.py. Django 1.4 standard directory structure is:

```
myproject
  |
  |--  manage.py
  |--  myproject
  |      |
  |       -- settings.py
  |       -- urls.py
  |--  myapp1
  |       |
  |        -- models.py
  |        -- views.py
  |--  myapp2
          |
           -- models.py
           -- views.py
```

What's the best way to change this dir structure to achieve what I want? Put models.py in myproject dir, put a file models.py in myapp1 which only imports everything from the former models.py and use "manage.py syncdb" to create the db tables? Is there a way to get the same result without the 2nd models.py?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just import models from one app in the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to create an app called `common` which includes utilities, basemodels, utility base test classes that all (or multiple apps) share.

You can create a `common` app and just put the `models.py` file in there.  As long as you register it you can use `manage.py syncdb` and just import its classes where you need them.